# Android - Get Item of my ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-checkbox

I use a `FragmentList` and i need to `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of my `ChechBox` So i need to ***get a reference of my CheckBox item*** ..  i have tried to inflate my item that contain my CheckBox but they are the container parameter .. so it doesn't work!

**SearchFragment.java**

```
Class SearchFragment extends ListFragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener
```

**Item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="Agadir"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"           
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting the listener on your checkbox instead of letting your activity implementing?

Like this:

```
  checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: the problem is getting the reference of my checkbox !